# Is there a set of standards for data validation rules?

Tags: data, validation, standards

I'm trying to develop a generic data validation engine for web forms.  Basically, the idea is to write a library that loads a JSON "validation schema", and then generates the appropriate server-side and client-side validation rules for various data validation libraries.

It seems like everyone has their own set of validation rule names.  For example, suppose you need to check that a string has a minimum number of characters.  In the server-side library [Valitron](https://github.com/vlucas/valitron), the rule is called `lengthMin`.  In the client-side library [bootstrapvalidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/), it's called `stringLength`.

My question is, is there any kind of standard out there (ANSI, ISO, etc) for the rule names and parameter names of common data validation rules?

Comment: I wasn't asking for a recommendation.  I was asking about the existence of a specific standard.

Comment: Well, after many months I have discovered that such a thing does exist: http://json-schema.org/
Too bad this question has been closed, or I could answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no standards for naming conventions by any major working group.  The closest you might get would be standards within an organisation or for a particular product so you are effectively free to choose the names that you feel are best.

Maybe pick the best of some already great implementations (e.g. ActiveRecord Validations / Flask WTF etc.).  You can't go wrong borrowing from them.